# Unity cant find my script while trying to playtest

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hboIq.png)I made a third-person controller with help of a tutorial, then I proceeded to add the script to the capsule I put in place.

but somehow when I try to test it out it says it cant find the script, I've tried to locate the script, which I found in my assets folder, is it not supposed to be there? but then where is it supposed to be?

its also not an error in the script because it didn't show any error in the standalone file

[Character hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJJld.png)

I'm not allowed to post pictures yet, but this is my character hierarchy

I got a error saying it couldn't find a monobehaviour or it didn't match the name of the file, the name does match the file but I think something is broken regarding the monobehaviour itself
[the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hboIq.png)

Comment: There is most likely a public reference on the script you are missing. Would you mind attaching a photo of what the hierarchy of the script on your player looks like?

Comment: So .. are there any compiler errors?

Comment: There could be a linking error between your script name and the class name in the actual script. The script file name is `thirdpersonmovement` from your screenshot, but what is the class called inside of this script? If it does not match, it will not be able to compile and reference the script properly to attach as a component to your object.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, please ensure to post your code in a `code block`, rather than as an image.

There is a lack of information to ascertain the exact cause of your issue, but as was mentioned it's likely a compiler error.

Your MonoBehaviour doesn't exist because it can't be compiled due to a lack of curly brace on line 29

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class thirdpersonmovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public thirdpersonmovement controller;

    public float speed = 6f;


    void Start()
    {

    }


    void Update()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;

        if (direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
        {
            controller.Move(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}//<-- This brace is missing in your example code
```

It also seems like you may have two versions of the class **thirdpersonmovement**, which may also be causing issues. You make a reference to **controller** which we will assume you assign in the inspector, but as you are showing us the code for the class **thirdpersonmovement** it can be assumed that **Move** either doesn't exist in this class, or exists in a duplicate definition of a class of the same name.